# Display nodejs query results on webpage using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose to create data objects but I'm having trouble displaying these objects on a webpage. I added the following query to my users.js file:

```
module.exports.getAllUsers = function(callback){
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err){
      res.send('error');
      next();
    }
    res.json(users);
  });
}
```

I'm then using handlebars to display the list of users on my template webpage:

```
{{#each users}}
   <h4 class="name">{{user.name}}</h4>                              
{{/each}}
```

I have users in my table but I don't see any results. What am I missing?

Thanks!!

EDIT 1: here's the full users.handlebars file:

```
    <div class="main-container">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb64 mb-xs-24">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <h3>users</h3>
                    <p class="lead">

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section><section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="horizontal-tile">
                                              {{#each users}}
                            <div class="tile-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="background-image-holder">
                                        <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="img/project-single-1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile-right bg-secondary">
                                <div class="description">
                                    <h4 class="mb8">{{this}}</h4>
                                    <h6 class="uppercase">
                                        Graphic Design
                                    </h6>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                        {{/each}}
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section></div>
```

Here's the users.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  tokens: [{
    access: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getAllUsers = function(callback){
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err){
      res.send('error');
      next();
    }
    res.json(users);
  });
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{this.name}}` instead. `this` represents the element being iterated over.

http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just updated it to `this` but it's still not loading any content

Comment: Can we see some more code where you're actually rendering the template?

Comment: Sure. I'll add the handlebars template now

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you want to use `{{this.name}}` where you have just `{{this}}`.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to see the JS where you are actually calling the handlebars render function.

Comment: just added! Thanks again for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function expect callback to be passed as argument and called, but this not happens.
2. You use 'res' object and methods `res.json()`, but are you sure that you have it there?
3. Are you sure that res.end() is not called before you got response from DB?